# How can I use promises to get Google Places data?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, promise, deferred, google-places

I'm trying to get data for multiple Google Places and then plot markers for each place on a map. I'm trying to use promises to wait until data for each place has been retrieved before updating the map. This is what I have:

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map),
    promises = [],
    promise = '',
    searchCallback = function(results, status) {

        if(status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

            for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

                var place = results[i];

                // this works
                console.log(place);

                // resolve the promise
                promise.resolve(place);
            }
        }
    }

$('li').each(function(index) {

    promise = $.Deferred(),

    var lng = $(this).attr('data-longitude'),
        lat = $(this).attr('data-latitude'),
        name = $(this).text(),
        latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        request = {
            location: latLng,
            radius: '500',
            query: name
        };

    // push promise into array
    promises.push(promise);

    // get data about place
    service.textSearch(request, searchCallback);
}

// when all promises are complete
$.when.apply($, promises).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

My `PlacesService` is working fine. I can `console.log(place)` and I see the object returned by Google, but when I try `console.log(data)` in my `$.when` callback, `data` returns undefined. It would seem my promises aren't working properly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

As written with `promise` as an outer var :

- there can only ever be a maximum of one Deferred assigned to `promise`.
- on completion of the `$('li').each()` loop, that Deferred will be the *last* one assigned within the loop.
- the first `service.textSearch()` to successfully return results will cause that last promise to resolve.
- subsequent successes will attempt to resolve the same promise but will fail to do so because a promise can be resolved only once.

So whereas the `promises` array will correctly contain all the Deferreds generated, only the last one will be resolved. All the other Derferreds will remain "pending" and `$.when.apply($, promises)` will never resolve.

The recommended strategy for this type of problem is :

- to promisify at the lowest level.
- to handle the data at the highest level.

For error handling, there's a design choice to make. You can either :

- allow any individual async error to scupper the whole edeavour, or
- recover from individual async errors by handling them and injecting a default value.

In this case, the second option seems the most appropriate.

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

// Promisify service.textSearch() as service.textSearchAsync()
// (lowest level)
service.textSearchAsync = function(options) {
    return $.Deferred(function(dfrd) {
        service.textSearch(options, function(results, status) {
            if(status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                promise.resolve(results);
            } else {
                promise.reject(new Error(status));
            }
        });
    }).promise();
};

// Map the 'li' elements to an array of promises, exploiting the low level utility.
// (intermediate level)
var promises = $('li').map(function(index) {
    return service.textSearchAsync({
        location: new google.maps.LatLng($(this).data('latitude'), $(this).data('longitude')),
        radius: '500',
        query: $(this).text()
    }).then(null, function(error) {
        console.error(error);
        return $.when([]); // error recovery (deliver an empty array) such that any individual failure of `service.textSearch()` doesn't scupper the whole endeavour.
    });
}).get();// .get() is necessary to remove the jQuery wrapper returned by $('li').map()

// Aggregate the promises then handle the data gathered
// (highest level)
$.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
    console.log(arguments); // jQuery.when() delivers data 'spread' into the arguments of its .then() callback
    var i, j, results, place;
    for(i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
        results = arguments[i];
        for(j=0; j<results.length; j++) {
            place = results[j];
            console.log(place);
            // now plot `place` as a marker on the map.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this work? Is this a viable answer? So much code and annotations and no answer checked, no upvotes, shame.